# How can I put quotes correctly?

Tags: php, quotes, double-quotes

I want to write an `onclick function` inside quotes but it throws error

```
$ad_div1='<div onclick="window.location="\"/"http://wwww/google.com"\"/"">xxx</div>';
```

How to add these quotes correctly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$ad_div1='<div onclick="window.location=\'http://wwww/google.com\'">xxx</div>';
```

If you need dynamic url use,

```
$ad_div1='<div onclick="window.location=\''.$url.'\'">xxx</div>';
```

Comment: what to do if i want to pass the url using a php variable? ie `$ad_div1='<div onclick="window.location=\'$x'">xxx</div>';`